# Trace Id not part of MDC, but is received in Spring cloud stream message headers

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, micrometer, micrometer-tracing

I have recently upgraded to spring webflux 3.0.6 with

micrometer 1.10.6

micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave 1.0.4

micrometer-tracing 1.0.4

I am consuming a message from rabbitmq where the traceparent is present in the message headers but the traceId is not there in the MDC. This is used to work with Spring cloud sleuth. Isnt Micrometer supposed to open a scope and transfer the traceparent trace and span info to the MDC?